# How to set label on curselection of Listbox tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, select, tkinter, listbox, listboxitem

Hi I am trying to set a Label based upon a Listbox selection based on some other questions I have found here.

Below is the relevant code I am using. Please excuse me if I have not posted correctly I am trying to post only the relevant code as requested and this all runs except for the errors I get when running it.

ERROR IS: `print 'You selected item %d: "%s"', % (index, value)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

```
#Show selected currency for from in label
frmcur_text = tk.StringVar()
frmcur = tk.Label(root, textvariable=frmcur_text, font="Helvetica 10 bold", anchor='w', background='lightgrey').place(x=195,y=50)

def onselect(event):
    # Note here that Tkinter passes an event object to onselect()

    w = event.Listbox
    index = int(w.curselection()[0])
    value = w.get(index)
    print 'You selected item %d: "%s"', % (index, value)

#Create listboxes for xurrency selection
listbox1 = tk.Listbox(root, font="Helvetica 11 bold", height=3, width=10)
listbox2 = tk.Listbox(root, font="Helvetica 11 bold", height=3, width=10)


listbox1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselect)    

cs = listbox1.curselection()

frmcur_text.set(cs)
```

Comment: You have a `%` immediately after a `,`, which is indeed illegal syntax. You need to remove the `,`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Hi Bryan I am almost finished with my code and was wondering if you would like to help me finish some logical confusion I am having do not want to post here as too long, valuable and a bit confusing to explain maybe you could open a private chat or flick me an email address so I could email you either a link or a .py your preference of course. If you dont have the time or simply dont want to no worries thnx for previous help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Spyder and Python 3.6 Answer

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("612x417")
root.title("change label on listbox selection")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.configure(background='lightgrey')


#Show selected currency for from in label
frmcur_text = tk.StringVar()
frmcur = tk.Label(root, textvariable=frmcur_text, font="Helvetica 10 bold", anchor='w', background='lightgrey').place(x=195,y=50)

def onselect(evt):
    # Note here that Tkinter passes an event object to onselect()

    w = evt.widget
    index = int(w.curselection()[0])
    value = w.get(index)
#    print ('You selected item %d: "%s"' % (index, value))
    frmcur_text.set(value)

#Create listboxes for xurrency selection
listbox1 = tk.Listbox(root, font="Helvetica 11 bold", height=3, width=10)
listbox2 = tk.Listbox(root, font="Helvetica 11 bold", height=3, width=10)
listbox1.place(x=300,y=50)
listbox2.place(x=300,y=125)


for i in range(20):
    i = i + 1
    listbox1.insert(1, i)
    listbox2.insert(1, i)


listbox1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselect)    

cs = listbox1.curselection()

frmcur_text.set(cs)

root.mainloop()
```